# AWS IoT Button Issue with Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have a Lambda function which is executed by a rule with a query of

`SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/#'`

In CloudWatch monitoring, it seems to be executing the button click many times in a few minutes period (sometimes it's about 2 per minute but appears to be random), and so this invokes the Lambda function just as many times, however, I need it to only execute once per button click, not multiple times.

I have deleted the same button from AWS IoT core many times so maybe it's not deleting them from the IoT SQL database, and so invoking the Lambda function for each instance of my button in the SQL DB?

Could anybody provide any guidance on this please? Is there a way to access the IoT SQL database? If my question doesn't make much sense, I'll try to re-word it.

Comment: There is no IoT SQL database. The select query looks like SQL, but it is used for filtering IoT events, it is not querying a SQL/Relational database anywhere. I suggest logging all the event data your Lambda function is receiving and examine the events for any differences. My guess is the IoT button is triggering multiple event types, and you really only need to subscribe to one of those events. Right now you are subscribed to all event types via `SELECT *`

Comment: please post your Lambda function.